# Add trustStore for client authentication

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, truststore

A [server](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/samples/sockets/server/ClassFileServer.java) and respective [client](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/samples/sockets/client/SSLSocketClientWithClientAuth.java) support client authentication but as noted here: [SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548807/sslhandshakeexception-no-cipher-suites-in-common), do not have trustStore reference, i.e. they use the default trustStore. How can the trustStore be specified?

**ClassFileServer:**

```
private static ServerSocketFactory getServerSocketFactory(String type) {
    if (type.equals("TLS")) {
        SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = null;

        Properties systemProps = System.getProperties();
        systemProps.put( "javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cacerts.jks");
        systemProps.put( "javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "p@ssw0rd");
        System.setProperties(systemProps);

        try {
            // set up key manager to do server authentication
            SSLContext ctx;
            KeyManagerFactory kmf;
            KeyStore ks;
            char[] passphrase = "p@ssw0rd".toCharArray();

            ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            ks.load(new FileInputStream("keystore.jks"), passphrase);
            kmf.init(ks, passphrase);
            ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

            ssf = ctx.getServerSocketFactory();
            return ssf;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**SSLSocketClientWithClientAuth:**

```
    try {

        /*
         * Set up a key manager for client authentication
         * if asked by the server.  Use the implementation's
         * default TrustStore and secureRandom routines.
         */
        Properties systemProps = System.getProperties();
        systemProps.put( "javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cacerts.jks");
        systemProps.put( "javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
        System.setProperties(systemProps);

        SSLSocketFactory factory = null;
        try {
            SSLContext ctx;
            KeyManagerFactory kmf;
            KeyStore ks;
            char[] passphrase = "changeit".toCharArray();

            ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

            ks.load(new FileInputStream("keystore.jks"), passphrase);

            kmf.init(ks, passphrase);
            ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

            factory = ctx.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        }

        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the `trustStore` by setting the system properties:

`System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cacerts.jks");`

or via command line invocation:

`-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path/to/keystore.jks`

Comment: I would +1 this answer if you pointed out how to do it ...

Comment: What is/are `systemProps`?

Comment: systemProps are system properties, have clarified answer.

Comment: Your command-line version sets the keystore, not the truststore. You could clarify it a lot better by *removing* the obscure part about `systemProps`.

Comment: Updated question and response.

Answer (score 1):

'No cipher suites in common' is not caused by using the default truststore. It is caused by not having a keystore, or not having a private key and certificate in it, or else by overspecifying cipher suites at one peer or the other such that there can be no agreement.

If the server doesn't have a private key, it can't use any cipher suites except the insecure anonymous ones, which are disabled by default, and should stay that way. Hence the alert.

Using the default truststore will cause a *different* problem *if and only if* you are using self-signed certificates. Simple solution: don't. More complex solution: export the respective certificates from the respective keystores and import them into the *other party's* truststore.

See the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html).

Comment: Added systemProps which works but does not seem graceful and I recall reading *somewhere* that is not ideal (though I cannot find that reference)?

Comment: @Astron look harder, at the part about using custom TrustManagerz.

Comment: I see references to using a custom TrustManger [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CustomizingStores), but do not see where to read a `trustStore` verse `keyStore`, almost seems to be one in the same.

Comment: @Astron They are the same file format but they have different functions. Create a `TrustManagerFactory` as shown, load it from your truststore, create the `SSLContext`, create your SSL sockets.