# Add custom truststore to imaps in java

Tags: java, ssl, imap, truststore

I use SMTP for mail and to retrieve mails I use imaps (imap + ssl):

Inside connect method I do:

```
private Session connect(SMTPTask task) {

    SSLSocketFactory factory = null;
    try {
        SSLContext ctx;
        KeyManagerFactory kmf;
        KeyStore ks;
        char[] passphrase = "changeit".toCharArray();

        ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

        ks.load(new FileInputStream("truststore.jks"), passphrase);

        kmf.init(ks, passphrase);
        ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

        factory = ctx.getSocketFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error with SSLFactory",e);
    }

    String host = getHost();
    String port = String.valueOf(getPort());

    Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator(task);


    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.submitter", authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName());
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    //properties.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.login.disable", "true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", port);
    properties.put("mail.imaps.ssl.socketFactory", factory);
    properties.setProperty("mail.imap.port", "993");

    Properties systemProps = System.getProperties();
    systemProps.put( "javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "truststore.jks");
    systemProps.put( "javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
    System.setProperties(systemProps);

    return Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator);
```

And somewhere else I do:

```
...
store.connect(getHost(),getUser(),getPass());
...
```

**Edit:** AND here I get the following Exception:

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Now I want to add a custom truststore with own certificates. Another post shows how to do that in java: [Add trustStore for client authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552725/add-truststore-for-client-authentication)

But how can I combine the SSLSocketFactory with my Store? So my store uses the custom ssl connection?

What is the correct way of doing that? If thats not possible, is there another way how to add my truststore to the store in java?

**Edit:** What am I missing, or did I do something wrong in the properties?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You pass the socket factory in via the properties map used to create the `Session`

```
Properties props = new Properties();
// other properties as usual
props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.socketFactory", new MyCustomSSLSocketFactory());
Session sess = Session.getInstance(props);
```

See the table at the bottom of the [com.sun.mail.imap package summary](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html) for full details.

Comment: For the `imaps` protocol it is property `mail.imaps.ssl.socketFactory`.